# What a browsers supports getNamedFlows？

Tags: javascript, css

I saw a codepen but it's not work because Object(HTMLDocument) has no method 'webkitGetNamedFlows'.
http://codepen.io/cjgammon/pen/okmGu

And I found the method should be supported by Chrome20+ on the webplatform. 
http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/document/getNamedFlows

I try to run the code on Chrome Canary 33.0.1702.2 and it's still not work.

My question is how to correctly run the code?

Comment: `w` should be caps I suppose.. `WebkitGetNamedFlows`.

Comment: You have to enable some flags: http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/enable/

Comment: @Mr_Green `WebkitGetNamedFlows` still not work.